# how to convert values from database to be numeric?

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I'm grabbing all the values of a column using:

```
> myValues <- dbGetQuery(mydb,"select average_Medicare_allowed_amt from STAGING_MEDICAREPUF")
```

because the values are defined as `varchar`, when I do a `summary(myValues)` r is not recognizing that the values are numerical:

[image]

Assuming I have no access to the backend schema, and am unable to cast the varchars to decimals, **is it possible to first convert myValues to be numerical and then get a summary?**

Comment: Have you tried CAST(average_Medicare_allowed_amt AS INT) in your query?

Comment: @legohead i have not. i will try it; however, i wanted to know if there was something i can do on r's side

Comment: is there a reason you want to do it in r as opposed to in the query?

Comment: @legohead, yes i want to know how to do it in r because sometimes i do not have "cast" permissions

Comment: I've never heard of cast permissions being blocked sorry, hopefully someone else can chip in.

Comment: @legohead well i was just wondering if you knew howt o convert to numeric in r

Comment: I've never personally used `r` so I don't know. I found this after a quick google https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strtoi.html. Essentially apply this and then do the summary to that value (this is however all speculation and may not work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, I find that the easiest way to convert to a number value is to simply add zero:

```
select (average_Medicare_allowed_amt + 0) as average_Medicare_allowed_amt
```

Note that the use of the column alias.  This allows you to refer to the resulting value using the same name.

MySQL does "silent" conversion.  If it encounters an error or a non-numeric character, then the conversion stops.  So, `'abc' + 0` returns `0` instead of generating an error.

And, regarding your comment, I have never heard of "cast()" permissions in any database.